# Is it possible to enable access to a URL without the .html extension but not redirect? (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know how to redirect all URLs to the version that does not contain the `.html` extension, but I cannot seem to find how to allow pages to be accessed *with* **and** *without* the `.html` extension.

Comment: Don't just down vote and not explain why.

Comment: Yes it is possible is the answer. In future be specific with exact problem we can replicate. -1 because this is easily google-able.

Comment: In hindsight, I see that the answer was right in front of me but I asked the question because Google didn't pull up any answers for "enable access to a URL without the .html extension but not redirect". There were many answers for accessing the html with a redirect but not without. Now, if anyone Google's the question, they're have an answer. Feel free to turn that frown upside-down.

Comment: Look, I understand you did try to search, it was simply not enough. Most questions currently on SO are already answered somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access .html pages without extension, you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

You can also enable muliviews on your server to access all files without using their extensions, to enable multiviews, add the following line to your htaccess

```
Options +Multiviews
```